# MySql unknown column in field list error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert, insert-update

I have a mysql unknown column error 1054. i can't insert in my database table
my insert function

```
    public void Insert(string tablename ,string[] values, string[] columns)
        {
            string col = "(";
            for (int x = 0; x < columns.Length; x++)
            {
                if (columns[x] == columns.Last())
                    col += columns[x];
                else
                if (columns.Length > 1)
                    col += columns[x] + ",";
            }
            col += ")";
            string val =  "VALUES"+"(";
            for (int x = 0; x < values.Length; x++)
            {
                if (values[x] == values.Last())
                    val += values[x];
                else
                if (values.Length > 1)
                    val += values[x] + ",";
            }
            val += ")";
            string query = "INSERT INTO "+ tablename + col + val ;
```

my query: return from the function.

```
"INSERT INTO rezervationinformations(Fullname,Phone,Description)VALUES(dsa,cq,q)"
```

called function:

```
    db.Insert("rezervationinformations",  new string[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text,
 textBox3.Text }, new string[] { "Fullname", "Phone", "Description" });
```

Comment: does it look to me like you are writing a wrapper for MysqlClient? Don't you are just breaking perfectly good code to replace it with bad code

Comment: Also leave a space before values here `string val =  "VALUES"+"(";`

Comment: Making SQL and db Ops in general just isnt  that tedious.  What happens when you need to insert/update a Date, Int or Decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is really bad, and not only it will cause errors, it is also exposing your database to SQL injection.

Just forget this useless function and use vanilla `ADO.NET` with parametrized query.

Or you can always use an ORM such as Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

You need to have quotations around your values, like this:

```
INSERT INTO rezervationinformations (Fullname,Phone,Description) VALUES ('dsa','cq','q')
```

Also, depending on your setup, you may need to specify the db:

```
INSERT INTO mydatabasename.rezervationinformations (Fullname,Phone,Description) VALUES ('dsa','cq','q')
```

Spacing between keywords is important too, make sure you are implementing whitespace where it is expected or the interpreter won't be able to understand what you're telling it to do. For the same reason when we, as humans, speak and write, we put a pause in between each word we say.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly quote all your query elements.

```
INSERT INTO `databasename.rezervationinformations` ( `Fullname`, `Phone`, `Description` ) VALUES ( "dsa" ,"cq", "q" )
```